# Rust Cross building with dockerfile

Tags: docker, rust, build, dockerfile

I have a simple software on my mac OSX in rust :

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("test log");
    Ok(())
}
```

I build a binary for linux (ubuntu) on my CI (Azure Devops) with Docker and extract it for run it on a vm doesn't have docker.

When i run it i have a Segmentation fault (core dumped) and don't know why ...

If someone has a solution there is my dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as cargo-build

ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Update default packages
RUN apt-get -qq update

# Get Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get install -y -q \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    make \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    curl



# Get Rust; NOTE: using sh for better compatibility with other base images
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

# Add .cargo/bin to PATH
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Recuperation des ressources
#COPY Cargo.lock .
COPY Cargo.toml .
COPY ./src src


# Build de la release
RUN cargo build --release
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide more error message? 

I tried with the command "docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash" and reproduce step-by-step your instruction and with the dockerfile. I can not reproduce error. My host machine is Windows.

Comment: Hi, no problem with image. If i run it with my docker image it's ok. 
But this image is for build ubuntu release on my CI and extract the release for run it on VM ubuntu without docker install. (I want only the binary).

Comment: In my test, I do "docker build -t testing/az-issue:2.0 .". If you run "docker run --rm  testing/az-issue:2.0 /bin/bash" and in other windows "docker ps" to see the container ID, "52c888fb7154" for me and "docker cp 52c888fb7154:/usr/src/app/target/release/app ." and copy app to your ubuntu and try to run it. It work?

Comment: Je vois que tu es suisse je vais te répondre en français ;). 
Mon CI run l'image docker et effectue ensuite un docker cp pour récupérer le dossier release. En gros ce que tu me suggères de faire. Donc j'ai bien le dossier release dont je prend le binaire que j'envoi sur ma VM et que je tente d'executer sans succès.  
Si je modifie mon image docker (de build) pour qu'elle execute le binaire ça fonctionne correctement..

Comment: Hello, ça doit être la cible alors. J'ai fait le test de mon côté et quand j'exécute sur une jessie, le programme fonctionne. Il n'y a pas d'erreur.

Comment: J'ai essayé sur vm ubuntu 16.04.6 et 20.04 j'ai la meme erreur moi ..

Comment: Tu as just un "Segmentation fault" comme message? Peux tu essayer un "strasse ./app"?

Comment: Je viens de faire la manipulation à la main comme tu l'as décrit et cela fonctionne. Je comprend pas pourquoi ... je vais devoir investiguer ;)

Answer (score 1):

We are found that's probleme is probably in pipeline (Azure Devops) description. Because when we do manually each step it work.

This issue is done? You are found solution?

Comment: Yeah issue is done, it was a cache problem on my Azure Devops